# Restricting admin acces to Azure Ad B2C User data

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

We have 3 people that need access to our Azure B2C portal pages. How granular are the permissions on the Profile page and All Users page?

We want to restrict the visibility of a User's first name and last name to a single administrator.

Can the User "Profile" page be restricted whilst the "All Users" page is still available to the whole admin team?

Is it possible to set visibility controls on specific fields? That would allow us to have the Profile page available but the fname and lname as hidden fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot control the visibility of the fields in the Azure Portal in this way. Yuo can only control which fields can be modified based on the [Azure AD Admin role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/permissions-reference) of the user.

The only option to provide more granular access would be to surface your own Admin tool built on top of the [MS Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-the-api).

Or there maybe a solution which a [partner offers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/partner-n8identity).

Comment: So that rules out controlling the visibility of fields. Can you contriool the visibility of the entire "Users" page?